# Magento display price in words

Tags: magento-1.9, price

We can get the Grand total using : `$order->getGrandTotal()`

but i want grand total in words means if grand total is **499** , then i need to display : **Four hundred and Fourty nine only**

Comment: where you want to display  this?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i want in custom pdf.....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really related to magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Magento way to convert this

But you can create function and get text by this example

Follow example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314997/is-there-a-way-in-php-to-convert-numbers-to-their-written-version

Comment: how i can make font size bigger and bold in this code result : `$page->drawText('PIN CODE : '.$shippingAddress->getPostcode() , 20, $page->getHeight()-360);` ?

Comment: play with this code `$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
        $style->setFont($font,12);
        $page->setStyle($style);`

Comment: thanks, but that will increase font size of entire pdf content right? but i want to increase and make bold for only some content in pdf.....

Comment: set this code before that content and again reset this code after that line , try out that way I haven't try this

Comment: @BabyinMagento You are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an third part for do this using composer

> php composer.phar update kwn/number-to-words

https://packagist.org/packages/kwn/number-to-words

Answer (score 1):

Using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500088/php-express-number-in-words)

I need this :

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format($order->getGrandTotal())
```